# Laravel Storage facade not returning good path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to upload some files to a specific "disk" in Laravel and then to retrieve the URL from these files.

Here is my `config/filesystem.php` file:

```php
'disks' => [
    ...
    'thumbnails' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/pictures/thumbnails'),
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
    ...
],
```

Here is the way I handle an uploaded file (very basic, just for testing purposes):

```php
Route::post('upload', function(Request $request) {
    $file = $request->file('file');
    $path = $file->storeAs('/', 'myFile.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension(), 'thumbnails');
    return dd($path);
});
```

The file `/storage/app/public/pictures/thumbnails/myFile.jpg` is created, which is fine, but `$path` equals `"myFile.jpg"` instead of the full path. First strange thing.

Then if I use:

```php
$url = Storage::disk('thumbnails')->url('myFile.jpg');
```

`$url` equals `"/storage/myFile.jpg"` instead of `"/storage/app/public/pictures/thumbnails/myFile.jpg"`.

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

By default the disk `url` method just prepends `/storage` as stated in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#file-urls).

To customize the url add a `url` to your config:

```
'thumbnails' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public/pictures/thumbnails'),
    'visibility' => 'public',
    'url' => 'the url',
],
```